# How do I call method with an array parameter and multiple other parameters in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

In Java, how do you call method with an array parameter and multiple other parameters? In this case, I try to call method `generateRandoms(int[] numbers, int low, int high, int count){}` in the `main()` method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Statistics_19711 {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void generateRandoms(int[] numbers, int low, int high, int count){        // semi-done
        //Generate random numbers within the range [low, high] and store them in numbers array
        low = 1;
        System.out.println("Creating 500 random numbers from 1 to " + count + ":");
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (high > 0 && high <= 100000) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                numbers[i] = rand.nextInt();
                System.out.print(i+ ((i-(0-1))%10==0 ? "\n" : " "));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input outside of range. Try Again.");
        }
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //the main() method should call the above methods. The main() method is then only method that does the input and output operation.
        System.out.println("This program creates random numbers and calculates some statistics.");
        System.out.println("Enter the upper limit of all generated random numbers:");
        int high = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the count(maximum of 100000) of random numbers:");
        int count = input.nextInt();

        generateRandoms(numbers, 1, high, count);
    }
}
```

`int[]` numbers are local variables in the method `generateRandoms()`. How do we call this method in `main()` and pass an array parameter without declaring any?

Comment: What do you actually mean by "without declaring any"?

Comment: you would get error, because you never declared "numbers" in your main method, neither did you give the "numbers" array a size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though your method is trying to create an array. The way you have it declared now, the array is being given as an input argument, which is why it doesn't make sense to you right now.

I think what you want to do instead is `return` the array, not have it as an input argument. However, that's not your assignment, so we'll make the array in main. I also changed your program to generate random numbers in your range using: `numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(high) + low;`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Statistics_19711 {

  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void generateRandoms(int[] numbers, int low, int high, int count) { // semi-done
    // Generate random numbers within the range [low, high] and store them in
    // numbers array
    low = 1;
    System.out.println("Creating 500 random numbers from 1 to " + count + ":");
    Random rand = new Random();
    if (high > 0 && high <= 100000) {
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(high) + low;
        System.out.print(i + ((i - (0 - 1)) % 10 == 0 ? "\n" : " "));
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Input outside of range. Try Again.");
    }
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the main() method should call the above methods. The main() method is
    // then only method that does the input and output operation.
    System.out
        .println("This program creates random numbers and calculates some statistics.");
    System.out
        .println("Enter the upper limit of all generated random numbers:");
    int high = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the count(maximum of 100000) of random numbers:");
    int count = input.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[count];
    int[] generatedRandoms = generateRandoms(numbers, 1, high, count);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generatedRandoms));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
This program creates random numbers and calculates some statistics.
Enter the upper limit of all generated random numbers:
20
Enter the count(maximum of 100000) of random numbers:
50
Creating 500 random numbers from 1 to 50:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: @Jaydasciencenoob I fixed method signature. Trust me, the numbers are random; they don't look random because we call `Arrays.sort`. Try running it with a much higher high bound.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use the int[] as an output parameter, which is not possible in Java. Instead, you should use int[] as the return value and create the array inside the generateRandoms method.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it e.g. like this:

`generateRandoms(new int[]{1,2,3}, 1, high, count);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily if you change the order of the arguments:

```
public static void generateRandoms(int low, int high, int count, int... numbers) { 
    // body of method
}
```

This allows you to call the method in any of the following ways:

1. `generateRandoms(0, 5, 3);`
2. `generateRandoms(0, 5, 3, new int[3]);`
3. `generateRandoms(0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

```
int capacity = input.nextInt(); // the capacity of the array
int high = input.nextInt();
int count = input.nextInt();
int[] numbers = new int [capacity];

generateRandoms(numbers, 1, high, count);
```

Comment: `count` is used only to be printed